# how to check if a URL is visible from the public Internet

Tags: networking

I often test web applications deployed in machines that are local on site (so I access them behind a firewall). Then (after the network people setup some port forwarding scheme) I invite other people to try them out only to be told that they can't seem to be able to see those URLs.

How to test whether a specific URL is visible / reachable from the public Internet?

I am aware of the existence of sites like [this](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) but do they test the actual URL (including context, etc. which will involve testing the actual port forwarding) or just accessibility of the node?

Comment: Can you please give an example URL!?

Comment: What do you mean with "accessibility of the node"?

Comment: @WernerHenze I mean weather they really test the entire URL or just check that the host is reachable (e.g. via ping, traceroute, etc)

Comment: downforeveryoneorjustme.com seems to only check if the host is up, not to check if there is a web service running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[GeoPeeker](https://geopeeker.com/) is a tool for web developers that makes it possible to remotely view a site from different geographic locations. It's great for spotting region-specific content and can be especially helpful when launching a site, as it can be used to ensure that the DNS is propagating properly. GeoPeeker is also pretty handy for troubleshooting CDN and caching issues. The images are rendered using WebKit with a screen width of 1280 pixels.

Comment: Does this work for IPv6 only hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Since your Web applications are *local* they have a local reserved IP addresses (corresponding to their URL) which Reserved Local IP Addresses are, by definition, unreachable outside the local area network...

Ref.: [Reserved IP Adresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)

Comment: The OP has mentioned that port forwarding is set up.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a [web proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy_servers) to achieve this.

[KProxy](https://kproxy.com/) is a proxy service I've used often to check whether I can access my computer from the web.

I've used it to check whether I've configured port forwarding properly. For instance if you're running a web server on your computer on port `7000` and have set up port forwarding on the service port `8080` you could test if the server is accessible from the web by trying to access this URL from a web proxy:

```
http://YOUR-EXTERNAL-IP-OR-DYNAMIC-DNS-HOSTNAME:8080/
```

Additionally, you can also check whether a specific port is open or closed and accessible from the web using a port checking service like [CanYouSeeMe.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org/)

Answer (score 0):

https://validator.w3.org/checklink is another web application checking URLs, but beware, it might not check every content.